# Assossiative Cache with 4 ways. Wrong tag, set, word?

Tags: c, caching

I'm making an associative cache simulator in C:
4 ways,
524288 bytes total size,
64 bytes block size,
32 bits addresses.

In this address:

```
00001000000000000000000100001100
```

what is the decimal value of the tag, the set and the word?

I think it's tag: 256, set: 4 , word: 12, but I have some errors in Hits and Misses and I think this might be the problem.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I get this:

```
000010000000000 00000000100 001100
000010000000000 = tag = 1024
                00000000100 = slot number in set = 4
                            001100 = offset in block = 12
```

Note: This is the same as your results except that the tag value is different by a factor of 4; which happens to be the same as the associativity. I'd be tempted to assume that this isn't a coincidence (and that you're consuming some bits for the "way" when you shouldn't be).